# radius of convergence for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^n+3^n+4^n) $ $x^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis

How do we solve it to get the radius of convergence
radius of convergence for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^n+3^n+4^n) $ $x^{n}$

Comment: Don't you recognize the sum of geometric series ?

Comment: Split the sum into three sums (with summands $2^nx^n,\ 3^nx^n, 4^nx^n$ respectively) and note that only the sum with summands $4^nx^n$ matters for determining the radius of convergence. From then on, assuming you know the radius of convergence of the geometric series, this is a straighforward matter.

Comment: why only it depends on $4^n$?

Comment: @amit: because it guarantees convergence

Comment: And think about $2^nx^n+ 3^nx^n+ 4^nx^n=(2x)^n+(3x)^n+(4x)^n$

Comment: taking these three differently..we will get three geometric series

Comment: I do think so. Go ahead and tell us your result ! Cheers :-)

Comment: we will get $\frac{(1-2^{n+1})}{-1}$ similarly for the other two..how do we solve it further?

Comment: If I may add a small question : when you finish, could you tell for which $x$ is the sum equal to 0 ?

Comment: by putting x=0.

Answer (score 1):

Find a convergence-radius for each of the following series:

- $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}2^nx^n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(2x)^n\implies[-\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{1}{2}]$
- $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}3^nx^n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(3x)^n\implies[-\frac{1}{3}<x<\frac{1}{3}]$
- $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}4^nx^n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(4x)^n\implies[-\frac{1}{4}<x<\frac{1}{4}]$

Then find the intersection of these radiuses, which is obviously $[-\frac{1}{4}<x<\frac{1}{4}]$.

Comment: @amit: You're welcome :)

Comment: You have shown that the radius of convergence is at least $\frac{1}{4}$. Might be worth pointing out that it does not converge for $x \ge \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: As J.J. says: in this case the above reasoning holds because no negative terms are involved. It would be a lot different for, say, $\sum(2^n-4^n+4^n)x^n$. I don't doubt barak manos knows perfectly that "$\sum(a_n+b_n)\text{ converges }\Rightarrow\sum a_n\text{ and }\sum b_n\text{ converge}$" need not hold, but it might be misleading for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the radius by considering the reciprocal of
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2^n + 3^n + 4^n}.$$
Now $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log(\sqrt[n]{2^n + 3^n + 4^n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(2^n + 3^n + 4^n)}{n}.$

Using l'Hospital's rule, we get
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^n \log(2) + 3^n \log(3) + 4^n \log(4)}{2^n + 3^n + 4^n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(1/2)^n \log(2) + (3/4)^n \log(3) + \log(4)}{(1/2)^n + (3/4)^n + 1},$$
which is $\log(4)$, so the original $\limsup$ is $4$, which gives the radius of convergence of $1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply $x^n$ by each of three term and check for what $x$ this can be expanded into three infinite sums